# Send contact form data to email

Tags: php, email, contact-form

My goal is to make a contact form, where the user would type their name, email and message. The moment they press "Send", me, as the admin, would receive an email with all the information that was typed in before. Right now the email is sent but its empty, for example:

> Reply to:
>   User name:
>   User email
>   User message

Also, when I click on "Send message" it gives me the same form but without CSS, there must be a code mistake which I don't know what it is.

```html
// Form contactos.php
<div class="col-md-7 mb-5 site-animate">
  <form action="index.php?cmd=contform" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NomeM" placeholder="Nome">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailMen" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message" class="sr-only">Messagem</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="Mensagem" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva a sua mensagem"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Mensagem">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```php
//File contform.php

<?php
$sql="select * from Mensagem ";
$res=$lig->query($sql);
$lin = $res->fetch_array();


$NomeM = $_POST['NomeM'];
$Email = $_POST['EmailMen'];
$Mensagem = $_POST['Mensagem'];


$email_from = 'admin03@happygreen.pt';

$email_subject = "New Form Submission";

$email_body = "User Name:" .$lin['NomeM']."\n".
"User Email:".$lin['EmailMen']."\n".
"User Message:".$lin['Mensagem']."\n";


$to = "filipajoao1933@gmail.com";

$headers = "De: $email_from \r\n";

$headers .= "Responda a: ".$lin['EmailMen']."\r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header("Location: Contactos/contactos.php");

?>
```

Comment: `input` (`select`, `textarea`) fields need a `name` attribute you can reference, yours only have `id`s. Also, the `for` attribute in `label`s reference the `id` of an `input` field, so `<label for="name"` should really be `<label for="NomeM"` etc.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and nothing changed

Comment: Shouldn't `"User Name:" .$lin['NomeM']."\n"` be `"User Name:" .$NomeM."\n"`? What is the purpose of the SQL query in the first place?

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL posts on Stack Overflow [are required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676).

Comment: I've not checked it, but isn't that header redirect going to add an additional `Contactos` *subdirectory* each time you submit the form?

Comment: Also, you submit the form to `index.php`, but your file is called `contform.php`?

Comment: @Ivar Because i want the data inerted in the file saved on my database

Comment: @Someone But you are doing a `SELECT` not an `INSERT`. Also you are selecting _everything_ from that table by not having a `WHERE` clause. Your `$NomeM` variable is only assigned but never used anywhere in your code.

Comment: @CD001 It gives my another form but without the css eveytime i click submit., im gonna edit the post and insert pictures

Comment: @kerbholz if my form action is "contform.php" it gives me an error, it needs to be that way

Answer (score 0):

Form fields (`input`, `select`, `textarea`) need a `name` attribute you can reference in PHP, yours only have ids. Also, the `for` attribute in `label`s reference the `id` of a form field:

```
// Form contactos.php
<div class="col-md-7 mb-5 site-animate">
    <form action="index.php?cmd=contform" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="NomeM" class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeM" id="NomeM" placeholder="Nome">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="EmailMen" class="sr-only">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailMen" name="EmailMen" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Mensagem" class="sr-only">Messagem</label>
        <textarea name="Mensagem" id="Mensagem" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva a sua mensagem"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Mensagem">
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And your `$email_body` should be:

```
$email_body = "User Name:" .$NomeM."\n".
"User Email:".$EmailMen."\n".
"User Message:".$Mensagem."\n";
```

Comment: I received an empty email, basically: **Reply to:  User Name:  User Email:  User Message:**

Comment: "Reply to:" doesn't show up anywhere in your code though, any code you didn't show?